# Alignment of span elements as td in table

Tags: html, css

How to make the span elements to be in a ordered manner as in table column ?
i.e how to make `step`, `glyphicons` and `X` to be aligned same as in table
(eg:glyphicons are moved up if we use span)

**Html**

```
<div class="row moving">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <span class="col-md-1"><h4>Step</h4></span>
    <span class="col-md-8"><textarea class="form-control"></textarea></span>
    <span class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span></span>
    <span class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span></span>
        <span class="col-md-1"><span>X</span></span>
</div>
    </div>

</br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1"><h4>Step</h4></td>
        <td class="col-md-8"><textarea class="form-control"></textarea></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><span>X</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.moving{
    margin-top:10px;
}
textarea{
    resize:none;
}
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/65s83vqz/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of CSS3 flexible box for your alignment. `align-items: center` will align the elements inside the flexible box container to be in the center of cross-axis(vertical-plane).

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pubf7n0a/)

```css
.moving {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
.moving .centered-vertically {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row moving">
  <div class="col-md-12 centered-vertically"> <span class="col-md-1"><h4>Step</h4></span>
    <span class="col-md-8"><textarea class="form-control"></textarea></span>
    <span class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span></span> <span class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span></span> <span class="col-md-1"><span>X</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
</br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-md-1">
      <h4>Step</h4>

    </td>
    <td class="col-md-8">
      <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span>

    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span>

    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><span>X</span>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Glad that was helpful, Ravi! :)